# Android Retrofit post Map<String, Object> including Array doesn't work

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit2

I try to post Map via Retrofit as follows.

```
ArrayMap<String, Object> map = new ArrayMap<String, Object>();

String key1 = "value1"

int[] intArray = {18, 29, 36, 12};


String[] strArray =  {"strValue1", "strValue2", "strValue3", "strValue4"};


map.put("key1","value1");
map.put("key2",intArray);
map.put("key3",strArray);


↓


@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("url")
void postSomething(
        @FieldMap ArrayMap<String, Object> params
);



Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .client(httpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

However, Array parameters won't work properly on the web server.

On the Log:
 intArray=notvalue&strArray=notvalue

What is an appropriate annotation of arrays or something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you want. Would it do to post your arrays as JSON arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [@FieldMap.](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded-using-fieldmap)

```
@FieldMap ArrayMap<String(field_name), Object> fields
```

Good luck

Emre

Comment: Thanks. I improve Model class, however not worked yet.

Comment: What's the response of server? Also http status code would help?

Comment: Thanks, On the Log: intArray=notvalue&strArray=notvalue

Comment: Looks like we are not in same page with the server. We need to know method signature of server. You sure it's urlencoded?

Comment: Basically, combine Retrofit with Okhttp. The logs are Okhttp's, not Retrofit. I try to look into Okhttp. thanks,